# How can I force Doxygen to show full include path?

Tags: c++, include, doxygen, code-documentation

How can I force Doxygen to show full include path?

What do I mean:

I have a class `foo::bar::bee` defined in `bee.hpp` in following directory structure:

```
foo
foo/bar
foo/bar/bee.hpp
```

Doxygen, when it documents `foo::bar::bee` class tells that you need to include `<bee.hpp>`, but for my software I need `<foo/bar/bee.hpp>`

How can I cause Doxygen to do this? Is there any option to provide "Include flags" like "-I" so doxygen would know where the base is?

Notes:

- `FULL_PATH_NAMES` is already set to default `YES`
- I do not want to provide include header explicitly for each class, because there
  too many of them. I want Doxygen to do this automatically.

Thanks.

**Answer**

Set:

```
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = relative/path/to/include/directory
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Taken directly from the hints in DoxyWizard:

> STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH
>
> The STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH tag can be used to strip a user-defined part of the path mentioned in the documentation of a class, which tells the reader which header file to include in order to use a class. **If left blank only the name of the header file containing the class definition is used**. Otherwise one should specify the include paths that are normally passed to the compiler using the -I flag.

Comment: Thanks... I feel stupid. I read this part of documentation and didn't understood one.

Comment: Well the name of the option suggests different behavior, so don't beat yourself up :)